# how to get fb page scoped user id for sending message

Tags: facebook

I want send message as shown link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#rate_limit
You can see parameter "USER_ID". How to get page scoped user id? please show screenshot and provide detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, there is no official method to connect user_id and page_scoped_id in both ways.
You can hack it by picture_url because both URLs are same.
see https://chatbotsmagazine.com/fb-messenger-bot-how-to-identify-a-user-via-page-app-scoped-user-ids-f95b807b7e46#.kcae9367y

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation say higher up on the same page:

> The recipient.id must be an id that was retrieved through the Messenger entry points or through the Messenger callbacks (e.g., a person may discover your business in Messenger and start a conversation from there.
>
> These ids are page-scoped ids. This means that the ids are unique for a given page.
>
> If you have an existing Facebook Login integration, user IDs are app-scoped and will not work with the Messenger platform.

Comment: What do you do with all your app-scoped data when you setup the messenger integration ? Do you have to maintain two entirely different datasets that live in different worlds or can you join them somehow ?

Comment: What do you mean with when you set up?

Comment: Say, I have a working login integration with an app. Now, I update the app to a new version that requests for messenger permissions and get a couple of users to upgrade. I now get both the standard graph api notifications and the messenger api notifications on the same rtu/webhook endpoint. Is there a way to join the page-scoped user ids I get from the messenger notifications with the app-scoped user ids I get from the normal graph api notifications ?

Comment: I have read before but did not understand how to do it. I use microsoft bot framework and webhook url not mine so I do not understand what to send to receive USER_ID https://facebook.botframework.com/api/v1/bots/3e81d154-b588-4829-971f-4efddc3b6bf4

Comment: Facebook will send you the page-scoped user id. After you get one you use that

Comment: sorry, what is that? my url? please provide detailed example

Comment: When the user message your app you will get a page-scoped user id. Then you use that id to reply

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/241178036245791?method=GET&path=me&version=v2.6 what is it?

Comment: Nothing to do with what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

I found no really & efficiently helpful information regarding this.

So I came up and tried to crack this. and finally gotcha!

to find `PSID` `page-scoped-id` for the user, you need to set up a messenger webhook or play with Graph Explorer. I used Graph Explorer for this purpose.

In Graph Explorer choose the page/app and then also select the required permissions related to messaging and managing pages etc.

then first you'll have to use the graph `conversations` API `page-id/conversations`

it will load the conversations with pagination. choose your target and then again you need to make another request with the conversation id `/t_2117846685221333?fields=id,name,participants`. this way it will list the conversations with PSID Page-Scoped-ID
[image]

the `id` data is your `PSID`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in official document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/get-started. You will need the following method with parameter "participants":

For curl:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/LATEST-API-VERSION/PAGE-ID/conversations?fields=participants&access_token=PAGE-ACCESS-TOKEN"
```

For Python:

```
import requests

page_id = '<your_page_id>'
page_access_token = '<your_page_access_token>'

# get PSID
response = requests.get(
    f'https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/conversations?fields=participants&access_token={page_access_token}')

print(response.text)
```

But before you get page_access_token. You will need to access Graph Explorer to assign permission and get token as stated in here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/overview/authentication/